# Introducing New Services in Runtime by Admin

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm using `ASP.Net MVC` with `Identity`,

In the `Registration page`, there are some categories

- Under each category there are some services, may be 3 or 4

The Admin wants to add new categories from admin panel and also add the services under each category he adds.

How can I map that with `ASP MVC` and `SQL Server` so that these categories can be shown in registration page as soon as the admin add them.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach

- Create a table to store the Category and Services
- So, Whenever a new category or service is added, the above tables are populated.
- Pull the details for the above tables on the user dashboard

So as soon as the details are added to the table the users can view the same